# Call glmnet from Rcpp (Armadillo)

Tags: r, rcpp, glmnet, method-call

I would like to extract `glmnet`'s coefficient estimates (after cross-validation) in `Rcpp Armadillo` to use them in another function of `Armadillo`. 
I searched for a similar question but I could not find a solution.

I attach my attempt. (Not working)
Even if I would get the list result of `cv.glmnet`, I could not use the `coef` function to obtain the coefficients.

**R code**

```
library(glmnet)

set.seed(1)
X = matrix(rnorm(1e3 * 201), 1e3, 201)
beta = -100:100
y = X%*%beta + rnorm(1e3)
cvfit = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1)
coefs = coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
coefs                                   # get these coefficients from Rcpp
```

Arguments of `cv.glmnet`

```
args(cv.glmnet)
> function (x, y, weights, offset = NULL, lambda = NULL, type.measure = c("mse", "deviance", "class", "auc", "mae"), nfolds = 10, foldid, 
    alignment = c("lambda", "fraction"), grouped = TRUE, keep = FALSE, 
    parallel = FALSE, ...) 
NULL
```

**C++ code**

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List f_cpp(const arma::mat &x, const arma::vec &y, 
                 const arma::vec &weights, 
                 const arma::vec &lambda, double alpha, 
                 int nfolds = 10){

  Rcpp::Environment pkg = Rcpp::Environment::namespace_env("glmnet");

  Rcpp::Function f_R = pkg["cv.glmnet"];

  Rcpp::Nullable<arma::vec> offset = pkg["offset"];
  Rcpp::CharacterVector type_measure = pkg["type.measure"];
  arma::vec foldid = pkg["foldid"];
  Rcpp::CharacterVector alignment = pkg["alignment"];
  bool grouped = pkg["grouped"];
  bool keep = pkg["keep"];
  bool parallel = pkg["parallel"];

  return f_R(x, y, weights, offset, lambda, 
             type_measure, nfolds, foldid, 
             alignment, grouped, keep, parallel, alpha = alpha);
  // coef(f_R(...)) ???
}
```

Comment: Calling an _R_ routine from _C++_ will not speed up the procedure. Have you considered only using _R_? If not, consider just calling the _C++_ routine with the `coefs` results.

Comment: You are right about the speed of the procedure. But I need to do this computation many times. It is very hard to move the `coefs` results manually.

Comment: Why is it hard to move `coefs` manually? What have you tried?

Comment: @Ralf Stubner Maybe I make a simple problem become hard. I don't know. But I add the code that I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling functions like `cv.glmnet` from C++ is complicated (maybe even impossible) since it uses quite a few possibilities offered by R that make the function signature very flexible. However, one can define a wrapper function in R that uses the actually used signature. Instead of getting this function from the (global) environment, I prefer handing it in as a function parameter:

```r
library(glmnet)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> Loading required package: foreach
#> Loaded glmnet 2.0-16

set.seed(1)
X = matrix(rnorm(1e3 * 201), 1e3, 201)
beta = -100:100
y = X%*%beta + rnorm(1e3)


# set seed since cv.glmnet uses random numbers
set.seed(1)
cvfit = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 1)
coefs = coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")

# set seed since cv.glmnet uses random numbers
set.seed(1)
my.glmnet <- function(x, y, alpha) {
    cvfit <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = alpha)
    coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
}
Rcpp::cppFunction(depends = "RcppArmadillo", "
arma::sp_mat f_cpp(const arma::mat &x, const arma::vec &y, double alpha, Rcpp::Function f_R) {
    arma::sp_mat coef = Rcpp::as<arma::sp_mat>(f_R(x, y, alpha));
    return coef;
}")
coefs2 <- f_cpp(X, y, alpha = 1, my.glmnet)

all(coefs - coefs2 == 0)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Of course, you can do more interesting things to the calculated coefficients than returning them to R. The explicit `Rcpp::as` is necessary since C++ has no way of knowing what type of argument the R function returns. In this case it is a sparse matrix, which can be converted to a `arma::sp_mat`. BTW, this looses the `Dimnames` of the matrix, which is why one cannot use `all.equal` for comparison.